# .Net Core Web Windows Authentication facing 500.30

Tags: .net, iis, .net-core, windows-authentication

I am trying to use dotnet Core 3.1.3 to release a React-Web application to an IIS server, where Windows Authentication enabled. I have tested with a success in debug mode, but faced a 500.30 error.

I tried to remove the line here and the application can run properly, without any features on Windows Authentications:

```
   webBuilder.UseHttpSys(options => {
        options.Authentication.Schemes = AuthenticationSchemes.NTLM | AuthenticationSchemes.Negotiate;
        options.Authentication.AllowAnonymous = false;
    });
```

Please help to advise which setting should I do for it with Windows Authentication feature?

Error from UI:

[image: HTTP Error 500.30 - ANCM In-Process Start Failure]

Errorfrom Log:

[image]

Here are some of the codes concerning authentication setting.

Startup.cs

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{            
  services.Configure<IISOptions>(options => { options.AutomaticAuthentication = true; });
  services.AddAuthentication(IISDefaults.AuthenticationScheme);
  services.AddAuthorization();  
            
  services.AddHttpContextAccessor();
  services.AddControllers();
}
```

Program.cs

```
        public static IHostBuilder CreateHostBuilder(string[] args) =>
        
        Host.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
            .ConfigureWebHostDefaults(webBuilder =>
            {
                webBuilder.UseContentRoot(System.IO.Directory.GetCurrentDirectory());
                webBuilder.UseHttpSys(options => {
                       options.Authentication.Schemes = AuthenticationSchemes.NTLM | AuthenticationSchemes.Negotiate;
                       options.Authentication.AllowAnonymous = false;
                   });
                webBuilder.UseIISIntegration();
                webBuilder.UseStartup<Startup>();
            });
```

launchSettings.json

```
 "iisSettings": {
    "windowsAuthentication": true,
    "anonymousAuthentication": false,
    "iisExpress": {
      "applicationUrl": "http://localhost:59811",
      "sslPort": 44331
    }
  }
```

Comment: You cannot call ˋUseHttpSys` here. Instead, open IIS Manager to enable Windows authentication and disable anonymous.

Comment: @LexLi I tried remove UseHttpSys and do the config in the IIS manager, which results that Active directory information cannot be loaded.

Comment: Can you edit the question to include the exact error page (like a clear enough screen shot)?

Comment: The error page is exactly same as the capture above

Comment: check the vent viewer log. which process hosting model you are using? try to set the OutOfProcess through Project--> Right-click -->Properties-->Debug-->Hosting Model.  did you upgrade your .net  core version?